Using Graphql for Server to DB call
I inherited a project, where they use Graphql on the server side to query Postgres DB. The Server itself is REST API based where there are separate endpoints for each resource & clients hit this endpoint. Golang is the server side language. Hasura is used as the adapter.
I understand the use case of Graphql for Client to Server interaction, but don't understand the rational behind using Graphql for Backend server to DB communication. Why to use one more intermediate layer while we can just use SQL. Anyway Hasura is gonna convert this GraphQL to SQL.
Why this unnecessary hop. Are there any advantages to this which I am missing.
